# $.fn.submit() event don't trigger inside an <iframe>

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, iframe

Simply speaking, I have a form, and a field.

```html
<!-- inner.html -->
<form id="inner_form">
    <input type="text" name="username" />
    <input type="submit" />
</form>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(function() {
    $('#inner_form').submit(function() {
        alert('Inner submit is triggered!');
    });
});
</script>
```

The above code goes well: when I click the submit button, it triggers the submit event of `#inner_form`, and alerts the sentence: `Inner submit is triggered!`

---

My problem is, when I make another page, and loads the `inner.html` inside an `<iframe>`:

```html
<!-- outer.html -->
<iframe id="the_frame" src="inner.html">
</iframe>
<button id="outer_submit">Submit Inner</button>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(function() {
    $('#outer_submit').click(function() {
        // it don't trigger the inner submit() event!
        $('#the_frame').contents().find('#inner_form').submit();
    });
});
</script>
```

As the above code (which might not working well in the snnipet), I click the `#outer_submit` button, and the `#inner_form` do submitted, but the event I defined inside it don't triggered!

---

Why do this happen? And if I want the inner event triggered well with outer action, how can I got it?

Comment: I'm not sure I get it, you included the first event handler in inner.html right ?

Comment: @adeneo Yes, the scripts in each snippet is inside the `html`, I will change the snippet to make it clearer.

Comment: Not sure if this is necessary, but did you include jQuery in the iframe document?

Comment: @Spokey you can check the code question, I update it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While I can't give you an answer as to 'why', here's some discoveries I made while testing this:

Replacing the `.submit()` action with

```
$('#the_frame').contents().find('#inner_form input[type="submit"]').click();
```

Will trigger the alert. This isn't a proper fix though, because there's more ways to submit a form. Still, it shows that the events are not completely broken. So I dug deeper.

---

I tried using native javascript events instead of jquery's `.submit([function])` bind in inner.html:

```
<form id="inner_form" onsubmit="alert('hi')">
```

That actually shows the alert. And so does this:

```
$('#inner_form')[0].onsubmit = function() {
    alert('Inner submit is triggered!');
}
```

So there seems to be something wrong with the way jQuery sets and/or detects its own `submit()` method.

---

One more try:

```
$('#inner_form').on('submit', function() {
    alert('Inner submit is triggered!');
});
```

This *also* shows the submit!

My wild guess is that for some reason when the events in `inner.html` are being bound, it doesn't know the form yet, even though the bind is wrapped in an implicit document.ready event through `$(function(){ .. });`.

As for the how and why of this I remain in the dark, but the fix is simple: wrap your event binds in an `.on()` method.

Comment: Finally maybe a stable way to fix it is to use an `<input type="submit" />` and then click on it.